# Accessing nested objects in JSON feed - Sencha Touch

Tags: json, sencha-touch, google-data-api

I'll begin with the usual disclaimer: new to Sencha Touch/working with JSON, floundering in the dark. Any help or prodding in the right direction is appreciated more than you know!

I'm trying to get my app to fetch data from a public Google Spreadsheet JSON feed. From what I've managed to figure out, my current model is based on JSON arrays, NOT nested objects. How do I access and return a nested object?

```
Ext.regModel('Count', {
    fields: [{name:'$t'}]

});

this.list = new Ext.List({
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div>{$t}</div>'),
            loadingText: false,
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                model: 'Count',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'scripttag',
                     url :  'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AuYDRk91MX8-dHhkV29ZVkRGNjlvZjV4QVBIVmJubVE/odb/public/basic?range=A1&alt=json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'feed'
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

The JSON data (extra stuff removed, above link will show all of it if need be, contains an email address I'd rather not post and have indexed):

```
{
    "feed":{
        "entry":[{
            "content":{
                "type":"text",
                "$t":"11"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

If I plop in another JSON feed that uses arrays I can work with it just fine, but just can't figure out what I need to do to access that integer in the object that corresponds to $t. If I put "entry" as the root instead of "feed," I get an error that reads, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."

Comment: Try something like: `root: 'feed.entry'` - that should get you one step closer to what you want.

Comment: @nelstrom Thanks! That got me marginally closer. Now, my list generates one list item (which makes sense, the JSON feed only pulls in one result), but I'm still not able to access the $t object contents. My updated regModel is as follows: `Ext.regModel('Count', {
    fields: [{name:'$t', mapping:'content.$t'}]
});`

Comment: @nelstrom Actually, I've got it working!! Turns out that the list item template didn't like that dollar sign in the {$t} variable. Once I switched it and the model to an arbitrary name with the mapping, it began working! `Ext.regModel('Count', { fields: [{name:'count', mapping:'content.$t'}] });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution! Turns out Sencha didn't like the $ in my template variable.

```
Ext.regModel('Count', {
    fields: [{name:'count', mapping:'content.$t'}]

});

this.list = new Ext.List({
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div>{count}</div>'),
            loadingText: false,
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                model: 'Count',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'scripttag',
                     url :  'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AuYDRk91MX8-dHhkV29ZVkRGNjlvZjV4QVBIVmJubVE/odb/public/basic?range=A1&alt=json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'feed.entry'
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```